# TOC and companion headings in memoir class

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, memoir

I'm writing my thesis in the `memoir` class, with the companion headings (`\pagestyle{companion}`). Following on from the TOC, I have the acknowledgements, abbrevations and abstract, before the introduction, which is marked

```
\chapter*[Introduction}{Introduction}
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the "Contents" heading above all the pages until the Introduction.

Is there any way to have no heading there at all?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I took the liberty of correcting what seems to be a typo: you probably meant `\chapter*` in the code. Also, could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks! Here is a MWE:

\documentclass{memoir}   \pagestyle{companion}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{KeepFromToc}    
\tableofcontents    
\end{KeepFromToc}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\newpage{}
\begin{abstract}
Abstract Text

\newpage{}
\end{abstract}

\section*{Acknowledgements}

\subsection*{{\small A subsection}}
Subsection text

\subsubsection*{{\small A subsubsection}}
more text

\cleardoublepage{}


\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter*[Introduction]{Introduction}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}

\end{document}

Comment: Apologies, I tried to enter line breaks in my MWE but they didn't come through.

Comment: My guess is I need to define a \pagestyle other than {companion}, and then switch to {companion} at the introduction. What is the name of the \pagestyle that will give me only page numbers and nothing else in the header?

Comment: I've now solved it, by adding `\pagestyle{simple} before the TOC, and \pagestyle{companion} before `\chapter*[Introduction]{Introduction}. Thank-you so much for your help!

Comment: Although, after doing this, my subsections and subsubsections are no longer numbered, in spite of having \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} in the preamble. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please update your question with a full minimal example instead of adding it in a comment. Also you might want to learn about `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`, then you don't have to use all those `*`-ed macros